# Undefined behaviour observed in C++/memory allocation

Tags: c++, memory, undefined-behavior

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a=50;
    int b=50;
    int *ptr = &b;
    ptr++;
    *ptr = 40;
    cout<<"a= "<<a<<" b= "<<b<<endl;
    cout<<"address a "<<&a<<" address b= "<<&b<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The above code prints :

```
a= 50 b= 50
address a 0x7ffdd7b1b710 address b= 0x7ffdd7b1b714
```

Whereas when I remove the following line from the above code

```
cout<<"address a "<<&a<<" address b= "<<&b<<endl;
```

I get output as

```
a= 40 b= 50
```

My understanding was that the stack grows downwards, so the second answers seems to be the correct one. I am not able to understand why the print statement would mess up the memory layout.

**EDIT**:

I forgot to mention, I am using 64 bit x86 machine, with OS as ubuntu 14.04 and gcc version 4.8.4

Comment: It is just *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: Not the case in VS2005. I run the code above with and without the `cout<<"address a " << .. ` line and the result is a=50, b=50 in both cases.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, it's all undefined behavior. The C++ standard says that you can increment pointers only as long as you are in array boundaries (plus one element after), with some more exceptions for standard layout classes, but that's about it. So, in general, snooping around with pointers is uncharted territory.

Coming to your actual code: since you are never asking for its address, probably the compiler either just left `a` in a register, or even straight propagated it as a constant throughout the code. For this reason, `a` never touches the stack, and you cannot corrupt it using the pointer.

Notice anyhow that the compiler isn't restricted to push/pop variables on the stack in the order of their declaration - they are reordered in whatever order they seem fit, and actually they can even move in the stack frame (or be replaced) throughout the function - and a seemingly small change in the function may make the compiler to alter completely the stack layout. So, even comparing the addresses as you did says nothing about the direction of stack growth.

Comment: Furthermore, even in the `&a` version it's possible for the compiler to inline `50` in the first `cout` line.

Comment: @melpomene: yep, maybe he's compiling with not very aggressive optimization settings.

Comment: I am not using any optimization flags and agree that this is not the way to find the stack growth direction. What you are guys are saying make sense but isn't it supposed to be like b is stacked below a in memory layout - at least hat is what we were taught? I was trying to exploit the way memory is laid out in a program/stack and not exactly bounded by the boundaries as in array and classes. Can't I exploit it this way?

Answer (score 2):

[UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) - You have taken a pointer to `b`, you move that pointer `ptr++` which means you are pointing to some unknown, un-assigned memory and you try to write on that memory region, which will cause an Undefined Behavior.

On VS 2008, debugging it step-by-step will throw this message for you which is very self-explanatory::
[image]

Comment: I am using gdb and it doesn't throw any error, I also went step-by-step there, but nothing of this sort came up.

Comment: Have you tried using Valgrind? I think it would help, not sure though. The msg thrown is not important here. Important is that you are trying to access the memory that is not assigned to you.